# baseURI Vs namespaceURI

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

Every `Node` instance has a `baseURI` property.

`Node` instances of `ELEMENT_NODE` type maintain `namespaceURI` property.

What are the significance of these two properties for a browser to manage the nodes in DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespaceURI is the namespace of the element. So for non-foreign elements in the HTML serialisation, that's `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.

The Base URL of a node is, in principal, akin to the `<base>` element in HTML. That element only sets the base URL for the document. But in XML, a base can be set on any element such that it applies to the `xlink:href` attributes of its descendent elements, via the `xml:base` attribute. The [XML Base](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/) spec describes this. Again, in principal, this should apply to XHTML documents (properly served as `application/xhtml+xml` of course), for example `<a>` elements in the svg namespace. However, a quick test shows that in fact, while Firefox supports this correctly, Chrome and IE do not.